# Strange service injection in Sling Servlet

Tags: osgi, aem, apache-felix, sling

We encountered a strange injection behaviour of service into our servlets. First serlvet looks as follows:

```
@Service(Servlet.class)
@Component(
        label = "Some Label",
        description = "Some description",
        metatype = true,
        immediate = true
)
@Properties({
        @Property(name = "service.description", value = "some val"),
        @Property(name = "service.vendor", value = "some val"),
        @Property(name = "sling.servlet.paths",
                value = { "/some/path" },
                propertyPrivate = false)
})
public class RequestPasswordServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

...
    @Reference
    private ValidateService validateService;
...
}
```

and the validation service:

```
@Component
@Service
public class ValidateServiceImpl implements ValidateService {

...
    @Reference
    private Service1 service1;

    @Reference
    private Service2 service2;
...
}
```

When request comes to this servlet, **validateService** is not null, but references inside this service are null, so I get NPE at some point. In OSGi console I see, that both components are active and their references are Satisfied.

There is even more strange thing - we also have second servlet (with just the same annotations, like RegitrationServlet), with reference to the same ValidateService. When request comes to second servlet, I can see, that references inside ValidateService are *NOT* null.

So I took heap dumps, where I see that there are two objects of class ValidateServiceImpl, which usually is ok, because second can wait for GC to remove it. But in this dump I can see, that servlets has references to different instances, what is really strange.

In both servlets, I wrote constructors and bind/unbind methods for this service. The output during deployment of package is:

```
2015-11-02 15:57:15.127 ERROR [com.package.registration.RegistrationServlet] Unbinding ValidateService
2015-11-02 16:01:47.159 ERROR [com.package.registration.RegistrationServlet] Creating RegistrationServlet()
2015-11-02 16:01:47.159 ERROR [com.package.registration.RegistrationServlet] Binding ValidateService
```

and

```
2015-11-02 15:57:15.106 ERROR [com.package.security.RequestPasswordServlet] Unbinding ValidateService
2015-11-02 16:01:47.104 ERROR [com.package.security.RequestPasswordServlet] Creating RequestPasswordServlet
2015-11-02 16:01:47.104 ERROR [com.package.security.RequestPasswordServlet] Binding ValidateService
2015-11-02 16:02:06.861 ERROR [com.package.security.RequestPasswordServlet] Unbinding ValidateService
2015-11-02 16:02:07.348 ERROR [com.package.security.RequestPasswordServlet] Creating RequestPasswordServlet
2015-11-02 16:02:07.348 ERROR [com.package.security.RequestPasswordServlet] Binding ValidateService
```

So RequestPasswordServlet (the one which has reference to correct service) getting created twice during bundle deployment, what I can not understand as well.

Whole this story can be related to next facts:

- our project runs on AEM 5.6.1 with SP 2
- version of *org.apache.felix.framework* is 4.2.0
- we moved to JAVA 8 and updated some versions of deps/plugins in our pom file:

  - org.apache.felix.scr.annotations from 1.6.0 to 1.9.0
  - maven-scr-plugin from 1.7.4 to 1.20.0
  - maven-bundle-plugin from 2.3.7 to 2.5.4
  - maven-compiler-plugin from 2.3.2 to 3.1

According to [this link](http://labs.6dglobal.com/blog/2015-09-14/felix-scr-plugin-compatibility-chart/) versions of *org.apache.felix.scr.annotations* and *maven-scr-plugi*, we use in our project, are not compatible, so I tried to change them to 1.9.8 and 1.21.0 respectively, but with no luck.

Also my steps to reproduce:

- clear install folder (to remove all our bundles)
- restart AEM instance
- install package1 (with version, when we first encountered this issue)
- install package2 any newer package
- check if issue is there

Restarting bundle/component helps to solve, but we would like to find reason for this weird behaviour and fix it.

Any ideas what is going on there, or where to look next?

**Upd1:** we also have this problem with other servlets/jsp pages as well. Also, it seems, that setting *immediate=true* for *ValidateServiceImpl* solves the problem (but not 100% sure about this), but this behaviour is not clear for me.

Comment: Why did you write bind/unbind methods yourself? The scr plugin will generate them for you. Also, making the references `volatile` might help

Comment: I may not explain the cause for the issues, but i did come across similar issues when i was updating our dependencies in our pom.xml. Some of the versions have inconsistencies. The versions we have are follows:
org.apache.felix.scr.annotations 1.9.12; maven-scr-plugin 1.14.0; maven-bundle-plugin 2.4.0; Not using maven-compiler-plugin.

Comment: @RobertMunteanu, I wrote bind/unbind methods to get some debug info. The issue is there, when they are missing as well.

Comment: @SurendraKonathala do you have Java 8 in your project? I am asking, because according to changelog of maven-scr-plugin in versions 1.15.0 and 1.17.0 there are important fixes for Java 8 support.

Comment: Sorry i missed this @Alex , we are on 1.7

Answer (score 0):

I think that AEM 5.6.1 is unstable with Java 8 :). It will be good with AEM >= 6.1 & java 8.